# Custom icon with ios and android

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have custom icons for ios and android with the name "md-usb.svg" and "ios-usb.svg".

I have copied the android icon to the folder

```
android\app\src\main\assets\public\svg
```

For the standard icon md-bluetooth.svg I found 7 directories. Which one is the correct for ios and which for android?

In the html I use

```
<ion-icon *ngIf="item.active" md="md-usb"> slot="start"></ion-icon>
```

I found in the documentation that we should use the asset folder but this folder also exists several times under the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Asset Folder

The folder you are looking for is not the ones hidden deep in the project.

From your `app` folder where you write all the code, just go up one folder and its in there `src\assets`

It's between `app` and `environments` in my project.

## Your method

It seems what you are trying to do is replace the actual svg file that `ion-icon` uses by default.

This is not the way to do it.

If you try this then it will be reset the next time a new ion-icons version is released.

You should put the asset in your local folder like `\src\assets\icon.svg` and then use it like:

```
<ion-icon src="assets/icon.svg"></ion-icon>
```

## Multi platform custom icons

This seems like there is an extra issue though which is that the custom file support doesn't seem to have platform support.

So it's going to get more complicated if you want to use different icons for each platform.

Broadly speaking I think this would need binding a variable to the src like `[src]="iconPath"` and then setting the custom url by detecting the platform using `platform`.

Update - yes I just checked the code. If the `src` property is set then it just uses that and ignores the `mode` so you would have to handle setting the correct icon for the platform outside of the ion-icon.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

https://golb.hplar.ch/2018/01/Custom-SVG-icons-in-Ionic.html

Under this link is a very good explanation about the integration of custom icons.
There is also mentioned the difference between ionic3 and ionic4.